# Form takes two clicks to update in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I have an issue with my popup form in my note-taking project. I have a popup form that shows up if user wants to edit a note, and that popup should already have the contents of the note they chose to edit. The form is showing the correct contents, but also I noticed that when I click on "Edit", it takes two clicks for the note to get printed (I suspect that I'm using `useState()` wrong but I can't pinpoint the exact spot where that's happening), and I'm wondering why that is. I've tried getting the data straight from the database, sending it to the form as props and , but I can't get to the desired result. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and would appreciate any help!

Here's my Note component:

```
import axios from "axios";
import EditNote from './EditNote'


function Note(props) {
  const [isEdit, setEditNote] = useState(false)
  const [idToEdit, setIdToEdit] = useState('')
  const [buttonPopup, setButtonPopup] = useState(false); 
  const [noteToEdit, setNoteToEdit] = useState({
    title: "", 
    content: "",
    category: ""
  })


 function deleteNote(id) {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/notes/${id}`)
    .then(() => { console.log("Note successfully deleted")
    props.setFetch(true)
  });
  }

  function changeNotes(id, title, content, category){
        setEditNote(true)
        setButtonPopup(true)
        setNoteToEdit(prevNote => {
          return {
                  ...prevNote,
                  title : title, 
                  content : content,
                  category : category
                };
              });
        
        console.log(noteToEdit)
        setIdToEdit(id)
        console.log(idToEdit)
    }
 
return (

  <div>
  {/* pass the notes array from CreateArea as props */}
  {props.notes.map((noteItem) => {
    return (
        <div className="note">
       <h1>{noteItem.title}</h1>
       <p>{noteItem.content}</p>
       <button onClick={() => {changeNotes(noteItem._id, noteItem.content, noteItem.title, noteItem.category)}}>
         Edit
       </button>
       <button onClick={() => {deleteNote(noteItem._id)}}>
         Delete
       </button>
       <p>{noteItem.category}</p>
     </div>
    );
  })}

  <EditNote trigger={buttonPopup} setButtonPopup={setButtonPopup} categories={props.categories} id={idToEdit} noteToEdit={noteToEdit} setEditNote={setEditNote} isEdit={isEdit}>
    <h1>popup form</h1>
  </EditNote>
  </div>
    )
  }
  
export default Note
```

and EditNote component:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default function EditNote(props){
    
    const [note, setNote] = useState({
        title: props.noteToEdit.title,
        content: props.noteToEdit.content,
      });

    function handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target;
        setNote({...note, [name]: value});
    }
    
    const updateNote = () => {
        setNote((prevValue, id) => {
          if (props.noteToEdit._id === id) {
            props.title = note.title;
            props.content = note.content;
            props.category = note.category
          } else {
            return { ...prevValue };
          }
        });
        props.setEditNote(false);
        props.setButtonPopup(false)
      };

    return (props.trigger) ? (
    <div className="edit-notes-form">
    <form className="popup-inner">
        <input
      name="title"
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={props.noteToEdit.title}
      placeholder="Title"
      />
      <textarea
      name="content"
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={props.noteToEdit.content}
      placeholder="Take a note..."
      rows={3}
      />
      <select
      name="category"
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={props.noteToEdit.category}
      >
      {
        props.categories.map(function(cat) {
      return <option
      key={cat.category} value={cat.value} > {cat.category} </option>;
        })
      }
      </select>
      <div className="btn-update-note">
            <button className="btn-update" onClick={updateNote}>Save</button>
            <button className="btn-update" onClick={() => props.setButtonPopup(false)}>Close</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div> ) : '' 
}
```

I also tried useRef, but it's not working as intended.
Would appreciate any direction on this, thank you!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to update a note, so when you click "Edit", a popup form populated with the note's content, title, etc is shown and then the user can edit and save the new note. I managed to get the popup form to work as intended but my issue is with getting the right note to update it in the database - I looked into it and as you've said, it's a problem with closure, but I'm not sure how to update it.

Comment: then you should create another question and ask about that specifically. The problem with a closure is just the tip of an iceberg here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tweaking the code some more the update note functionality is working as intended, I'm sure the code isn't nearly perfect, but maybe it helps someone!
Here's what I ended up with:

EditNote component:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default function EditNote(props){
    const [note, setNote] = useState({
        title: props.noteToEdit.title,
        content: props.noteToEdit.content
      });

    console.log(props.noteToEdit)

    function handleChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const {name, value} = event.target;
        setNote({...note, [name]: value});
    }
    
    const updateNote = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!note.title || !note.content) {
            alert("'Title' or 'Content' cannot be blank");
        } else {
            axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/notes/update/${props.id}`, note) 
                .then((res) =>{
                    console.log("Note updated successfully")
                    props.setFetch(true)   
                })
                .catch(err => console.log("Error: " + err));
        }
        props.setButtonPopup(false)
      };

    return (props.trigger) ? (
    <div className="edit-notes-form">
    <form className="popup-inner">
        <input
      name="title"
      onChange={handleChange}
      defaultValue={props.noteToEdit.title}
      placeholder="Title"
      />
      <textarea
      name="content"
      onChange={handleChange}
      defaultValue={props.noteToEdit.content}
      placeholder="Take a note..."
      rows={3}
      />
      <select
      name="category"
      onChange={handleChange}
      defaultValue={props.noteToEdit.category}
      >
      {
        props.categories.map(function(cat) {
      return <option
      key={cat.category} value={cat.value} > {cat.category} </option>;
        })
      }
      </select>
      <div className="btn-update-note">
            <button className="btn-update" onClick={updateNote}>Save</button>
            <button className="btn-update" onClick={() => props.setButtonPopup(false)}>Close</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div> ) : '' 
}
```

and Note component:

````
import axios from "axios";
import EditNote from './EditNote'


function Note(props) {
  const [idToEdit, setIdToEdit] = useState('')
  const [buttonPopup, setButtonPopup] = useState(false); 
  const [noteToEdit, setNoteToEdit] = useState({
    title: "", 
    content: "",
    category: ""
  })


 function deleteNote(id) {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/notes/${id}`)
    .then(() => { console.log("Note successfully deleted")
    props.setFetch(true)
  });
  }

  function changeNotes(id, title, content, category){
        setButtonPopup(true)
        setNoteToEdit(prevNote => {
          return {
                  ...prevNote,
                  title : title, 
                  content : content,
                  category : category
                };
              });
        
        console.log(noteToEdit)
        setIdToEdit(id)
        console.log(idToEdit)
    }
 
return (

  <div>
  {/* pass the notes array from CreateArea as props */}
  {props.notes.map((noteItem) => {
    return (
        <div className="note">
       <h1>{noteItem.title}</h1>
       <p>{noteItem.content}</p>
       <button onClick={() => {changeNotes(noteItem._id, noteItem.title, noteItem.content, noteItem.category)}}>
         Edit
       </button>
       <button onClick={() => {deleteNote(noteItem._id)}}>
         Delete
       </button>
       <p>{noteItem.category}</p>
     </div>
    );
  })}

  <EditNote trigger={buttonPopup} setButtonPopup={setButtonPopup} categories={props.categories} id={idToEdit} noteToEdit={noteToEdit} setFetch={props.setFetch}>
  </EditNote>
  </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default Note```
````

Answer (score 2):

As https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function states:

> Any function inside a component, including event handlers and effects, “sees” the props and state from the render it was created in.

so, in your code, `changeNotes` will log previous value of `noteToEdit`, not the current one. When you click `Edit` once more, this time the previous value and the current value is the same so it *seems* as if it's working as you imagine, but it's not. It will always log the stale value but it sometimes happens that previous value is still valid as when you click twice on `Edit`.

Answer (score 0):

setNoteToEdit is *async* therefore you're going to see the previous value in the console.log.

Also inside of setNote, in EditNote.tsx, you should pass as a prop the setNoteToEdit and use that to change the note to edit. That way the state change in the parent will trigger a render with the new values.

Comment: Thank you! I don't entirely understand what to change though, would appreciate some clarification :)

Comment: state setters are *mostly* async but this isn't the reason why a stale value is logged. It's closure here to blame. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

Comment: Thank you, I still am unclear on what to change, would it be `const [note, setNote] = useState({
        title: props.noteToEdit.title,  content: props.noteToEdit.content
      });` in EditNote?